# Cannot get more than 1Mbps with Intel Wireless-AC 9560 on Ubuntu 18.04 for 5Ghz band

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04

### Problem and details:

- Very slow wifi speed on the 5Ghz band in ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
- I can get better speeds with the 2.4Ghz connection (say > 60Mbps).
- I have 1Gbps rated internet connection
- I can get up to 600+ Mbps when I boot to windows.
- My Motherboard: Asus Tuf Gaming z390 Pro wifi

### What I have tried:

- I have tried all the solutions mentioned in the following post and nothing worked.
- https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/
- Please help.

  ### sudo lshw -C network output

  `*-network:0

     description: Wireless interface
     product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 14.3
     bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
     logical name: wlo1
     version: 10
     serial: 20:79:18:bd:cd:79
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.0-17-generic firmware=38.c0e03d94.0 ip=10.0.0.72 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
     resources: irq:16 memory:a4334000-a4337fff
  *-network:1
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1f.6
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
     logical name: eno2
     version: 10
     serial: 04:d4:c4:01:26:f4
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
     resources: irq:125 memory:a4300000-a431ffff
  *-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 2
     logical name: docker0
     serial: 02:42:03:f0:87:49
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes`

Comment: What was your solution? It used to be fine for me, fast, and all the sudden, after an update, it slowed down